# A function continuous on a closed interval and failing to have the intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the textbook of Bernard R. Gelbaum, John M. H. Olmsted "Counterexamples in Analysis Dover Books on Mathematics", page 19, they say that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ but does not assume the values $2$ intermediate between the value $1$ and $4$. I do not understand what they mean. For me, $\sqrt{2}\in [1,2]$ and $f(\sqrt{2})=2$.

Also, using the the intermediate value theorem, since $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ and $f(1)=1<2<4=f(2)$, there exists $c\in [1,2]$ such that $f(c)=2$.

Can I get some explanation about this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the text before that series of examples, the authors specifically say:

> We conclude this chapter with a collection of functions defined on a closed interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{Q}$ and having values in $\mathbb{Q}$.

So, we're not in $\mathbb{R}$ anymore.

Comment: Ahhh! I suspected this was the case. I had just asked the OP what was the domain.